# PHP function to compare two Roman numerals

Tags: php, algorithm, homework

This was for an assignment. I had to write a function to compare two roman numerals. This had to return `true` only if the second number was larger than the first and had to be done without converting the letters into integers. Also prefix subtraction didn't apply so all the letters came in descending order.

Here is what I came up with:

```
<?php

function x_smaller_than_y($x_num,$y_num) {

//Create array with ordered list of roman numerals. 
$evaluation= array("M","D","C","L","X","V","I");

//Splits submitted numbers into arrays
$x_num_arr = str_split($x_num);
$y_num_arr = str_split($y_num);

//Loops through each roman numeral in the given list
for ($evaluate = 0; $evaluate<7;$evaluate++)
  {  

     //For every letter in the numerals' list loops through 
     //every letter in the given numbers looking for a match.
     $counter = 0;
     while ($counter < ((strlen($x_num)))&& $counter < ((strlen($y_num))))
       {

       //If in any specific position x=y, it simply ignores it and moves forward.
       if ($x_num_arr[$counter]==$y_num_arr[$counter])
           {$counter++;}

       //If in any given position the letter in Y is higher in the list than  
       //the letter in X then Y is larger than X and the function is true. 
       //"break" ends the while loop and "$evaluate=8" ends the for loop.
       elseif(($x_num_arr[$counter]!=$evaluation[$evaluate])&&($y_num_arr[$counter]==$evaluation[$evaluate]))
           {return true;
            $evaluate=8;
            break;}

       //Same as above but this time the letter in X is before the letter 
       //in Y so the function is false.
       elseif(($x_num_arr[$counter]==$evaluation[$evaluate])&&( $y_num_arr[$counter]!=$evaluation[$evaluate]))
           {return false;
            $evaluate=8;
            break;}    

       //If none of the above cases apply simply move to the next letter.
       else {$counter++;}
        }
    }

//Since the number of iterations in the while loop is determined by the 
//shorter number there can still be a case in which 2 numbers are exactly 
//the same up to a point but one is simply longer than the other, 
//eg. MXVI and MXVII.
//When this happens the for loop will have run through its natural 
//course, $evaluate will be equal to 7, and the code below will determine 
//the larger number by looking at their lenght. 
if ($evaluate<8&&(strlen($x_num) < strlen($y_num)))
{return true;}

elseif ($evaluate<8&&(strlen($x_num) > strlen($y_num)))
{return false;}

}
```

How could have I made it better?

Answer (score 1):

It gives wrong results for `9` (`IX`) and `5` (`V`).

Some notes about the code:

1. In the following block the `$evaluate = 8;` and the `break;` statements are unnecessary, they never run because of the `return` statement.

   ```
   {
       return true;
       $evaluate = 8;
       break;
   }
   ```
2. Instead of commenting name the variable to what the comment says.

   ```
   //Create array with ordered list of roman numerals. 
   $evaluation= array("M","D","C","L","X","V","I");
   ```

   It could be `$numerals` or `$numerals_in_order`, for example.
3. `7` and `8` are a magic numbers. They should be named constants or computed values. Do they come from the size of the array? If they do make it clear, it would improve readability.
4. ```
   while ($counter < ((strlen($x_num)))&& $counter < ((strlen($y_num))))
   ```

   This could be simplified to the following:

   ```
   $size = min(strlen($x_num), strlen($y_num));
   while ($counter < $size)
   ```
5. Instead of big `if-elseif` structures you could use `continue` and simple `if`s since some of them returns the function if the condition is `true`, so the remaining code won't run. The last `else` also would be unnecessary.

   ```
   $size_min = min(strlen($x_num), strlen($y_num));
   while ($counter < $size_min) {
       if ($x_num_arr[$counter] == $y_num_arr[$counter]) {
           $counter++;
           continue;
       }

       if(($x_num_arr[$counter]!=$evaluation[$evaluate])&&($y_num_arr[$counter]==$evaluation[$evaluate])) { 
           return true;
       }

       if(($x_num_arr[$counter]==$evaluation[$evaluate])&&( $y_num_arr[$counter]!=$evaluation[$evaluate])) {
           return false;
       }    

       $counter++;
   }
   ```
6. Inside the `for` loop the `$evaluation` array is always indexed with `$evaluate`. You should create a local variable for this.
7. The same is true for `$y_num_arr[$counter]` and `$x_num_arr[$counter]` inside the `while` loop. (They could be `$current_x` and `$current_y`).
8. It might not be an issue (depending on the specification) but the function currently accepts invalid Roman numerals too (like `IIX`).
9. At the end of the function it returns with implicit `NULL` if both conditions are `false` in the following snippet:

   ```
   if ($evaluate<8&&(strlen($x_num) < strlen($y_num)))
   {return true;}

   elseif ($evaluate<8&&(strlen($x_num) > strlen($y_num)))
   {return false;}
   ```

   You should make this explicit (add a `return false` as the last statement) or use an [`assert`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php) call if it should never happen.
10. You could easily write some test code to check that the comparison is fine for every possible Roman numeral.

    ```
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++) {
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $max; $j++) {
            $i_r = numberToRoman($i);
            $j_r = numberToRoman($j);
            $smaller = x_smaller_than_y($i_r, $j_r);
            if ($i >= $j && $smaller) {
                echo "error: $i, $j, $i_r, $j_r\n";
            }
        }
    }
    ```

    If I'm right `$max` should be `3888` and it finishes in a few minutes. [You can find a `numberToRoman` function here, for example.](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=4948).

Answer (score 0):

My first comment is that your function needs a more meaningful name.  The current name tells us that it's for comparing something, but doesn't convey what.  If you rename it to something like `whichRomanNumeralIsSmaller ()` you'll convey more information about what the function does and what it's expecting as input.  Readability of code is one of the key contributors to the maintainability of the code.

On a similar note, your function's local variables don't have very descriptive names.  Again, a well chosen name is much more helpful than one like $counter.  What is $counter counting?

A lookup table for converting the numerals to values might make more sense than your $evaluation array.

```
$numeralLookup = array (
    'I' => 1,
    'V' => 5, 
    'X' => 10, 
    'L' => 50,
    'C' => 100,
    'D' => 500,
    'M' => 1000
)
```

You can now just pull the value for any valid numeral from the array. What's more, you can now also validate your input because if the numeral doesn't have a key in the array it must be invalid.  You can throw an exception or whatever you think is suitable in this case.

Finally, from a design point of view, I think maybe you might want to decompose the problem (break it down into smaller parts) further.  Your current solution provides you the ability to compare 2 numeral strings, but what if all you want to do is decode a numeral into an Arabic number?  The code is all there in your function but you can't directly use it because it's part of a bigger process.

I'd recommend that you simply write a decodeNumeral() function and then use PHP's internal number comparison features.

```
echo (decodeNumeral ($var1) > $decodeNumeral ($var2)? $var1: $var2) . ' is bigger';
```

(Yes, I know it will give a spurious result if $var1 and $var2 are equal, it's just for illustration)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However the assignment was precisely to compare the numerals without converting them to integers.